# Plot of a function defined by an integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, complex

(First of all, this is my first Mathematica question. I'm not used to Mathematica that much. So, apologies in advance.)

I need to plot the following functional with accuracy:

$$
I(x,s) =\int_0^\infty\mathrm dy \frac{F(x + \mathrm iy, s) − F(x −\mathrm iy, s)}{\mathrm e^{2πy}-1},
$$
Where $ F(z, s) = \dfrac{\sin^2[π\Gamma(z)/(2z)]}{z^s} $.

And let us restrict $s\in[0,1]$

Also, can we get quantitative upper and lower bound estimations on the functional using Mathematica?

The reason for the question is that the functional gives very massive values ( upto 10^100) after the value x=6 which I think are not correct. I don't know how to resolve this issue.So I'm posting this question for bigger accurate values

Comment: you defined $F$ as taking one argument $z$ but you are calling in using 2 arguments? What is `s`?

Comment: @Nasser thanks for correcting  see denominator $(z^s)$

Comment: If you looking for analytical integration, Mathematica can not do the integral at all `f[z_, s_] := Sin[Gamma[z]/z]^2/z^s;
Integrate[(f[x + I y, s] - f[x - I y, s])/(Exp[2 Pi y] - 1), y]` For numerical integration, need numerical values for the parameters involved.

Comment: @Nasser I'm looking for sharp approximation of the integral

Comment: `sharp approximation of the integral` I assume you mean by a numerical approximation. For this, numerical values are needed for all parameters other than the integration variable itself.  If you provide example of such values, may be someone could help.

Comment: @Nasser thank you for the answer , take $s=1$ and you can.give me table of values for $I(x)$ for various $x$'s . Also if you could numerically tell the nature of $I(x)$ for large $x$ or as $x$ tends to infinity it would be extremely helpful for me . And again very very thank you for your cooperation .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it numerically?

```
f[z_, s_] := Sin[Gamma[z]/z]^2/z^s; 
II[x_, s_] := NIntegrate[(f[x + I y, s] - f[x - I y, s])/(Exp[2 Pi y] - 1), {y, 0, 
   Infinity}]
```

Then

```
ParallelTable[{x, II[x, s] // Im}, {s, 1, 2, 1/2}, {x, 1, 5, 0.05}] //
  ListLinePlot[#, PlotRange -> All] &
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: thank you for the answer but as you can see the functional gives very massive values after the value x=6 which I think are not correct. So I'm posting this question for bigger accurate values